# Sort by value, key in case of equality

Tags: ruby

I want to sort a Hash in Ruby by value, then by key in case of equality.
I tried this but it returns the same array:

```
 hash.sort { |x, y|
  if x[1] == y[1]
    comp = x[0] <=> y[0]
  else
    comp =  x[1] <=> y[1]
  end
  comp
 }
```

Comment: Why do you want to sort a hash? There is very little value in it. Instead, grab the keys, order them how you want and use `values_at` to extract the values in the same order.

Comment: No practical reason actually, it was a pure academic question.

Comment: @the Tin Man This could be used to implement a simple priority queue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
hash.sort {|h1,h2| h1.reverse <=> h2.reverse }
```

or simply:

```
hash.sort_by(&:reverse)
```

If you want to have a Hash as response:

```
Hash[ hash.sort_by(&:reverse) ]
```

Comment: Use `sort_by`, instead of `sort`. It'll be faster.

Comment: Note that this returns an array of two-valued arrays. If you actually want a new hash, you'll need to wrap this in `Hash.[]`, e.g. `sorted_hash = Hash[ hash.sort_by(&:reverse) ]`

Comment: @Phrogz I edited the response to add your recommendation